# bootstrap nav bar overlapping div label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing around with this for a while and thought it's time to seek help. 
I have a container and within it there is a link and below the link there is a label and below that is the nav bar. 
I tried a few of the settings but haven't been able to get it right. 
For a moment I thought I had it.

[EDITED] Here is the code that i've been mucking around:

```
  <div style=" background-color:#f0f0f1; width:inherit;">
        <div class="container">
        <!--Page Title Section -->

            <div class="container">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <br />
                    <a href="#">Back to Link</a>
                    <p class="pagelabelspacer">
                        <asp:Label ID="PageTitleLabel" CssClass="pageTitle" runat="server">Page Title.</asp:Label>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.container-collapse -->
        </div>

        <!--End Page Title Section-->

        <!--Nav Bar -->

        <div class="container">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                </ul>    
            </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <!--End Nav Bar -->
    </div>
```

[EDITED] My questions:

1. How do i get the nav bar not to overlap the link and label?
   [My answer -> just put it in another container and it works]
2. On nav-default the height of the nav bar seems exaggerated (i.e. too high). Is there a way to change it (e.g. setting a specific pixel height)?
3. Is there a way to override the default nav bar color?

I'll continue playing with it to try to get it working.
Any suggestions and advice are greatly appreciated. 
thanks!

Comment: Please include the code here, also your link does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How do i get the nav bar not to overlap the link and label?**

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom

> Body padding required
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the bottom of the . Try out your own values or use
>   our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
>
> body { padding-bottom: 70px; }
>
> Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

**Is there a way to override the default nav color?**

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar

If you're using SASS or LESS bootstrap, has variables that you can change to manipulate various properties of elements.

Comment: Thanks DoctorDerp. I can't believe I missed that link in the getbootstrp.com site. It looks snazzy now.

Comment: Hope that sorted it for you, I had the same problem when I started using Boostrap.